# Convexity of the product of an Integer function and a convex function

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Assume $f_i (X)$ is a function that returns either $-1$ or $1$, and $g_i (X)$ is a (twice continuously-differentiable) convex function, and $h(X) = \sum_{i=1}^M f_i(X) \times g_i(X)$. $M$ is finite, and $X=\{ x_1,\dots,x_{N}\}$ is a finite set of variables with $N$ elements. My questions are:

1. Is h(X) continuous? (I guess not, because $f_i(X)$ is not continuous).
2. Is h(X) convex?
3. Does h(X) has a global (unique) minima?

Comment: I think you can answer all of these questions yourself with simple examples. Try $f = -1+1_{[0,\infty)}$, $g(x) = 1+x^2$.

Comment: Right. I did not think that way...